# Deleting the last line of my *txt which got generated by a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have generated (with the help of you guys) following code which combines .txt files and is renaming the file based on the content of the file! Thanks so far!

```
@Echo Off
    Set _Path=%~dp0
    PushD %_Path%
    For /F "Tokens=1 Delims=" %%a In ('Dir /A-D /B *.txt') Do (
    Echo %%a
    For /F "Usebackq Tokens=1 skip=1 Delims=" %%I In ("%%a") Do >>"%temp%\%%a" Echo.%%I
    Move /Y "%temp%\%%a" .\
    )
    PopD

    COPY %~dp0\PreSet.txt + %~dp0\Header.txt + %~dp0\Item.txt %~dp0\_BOM_.txt

    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "dir_with_files=%~dp0"
    for %%# in ("%dir_with_files%\*_BOM_*") do (
      set "date_="
      set "number="
      for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=3,4,5,6 delims=. " %%a in ("%%#") do (
         if not defined date_ (
          set "date_=%%a%%b%%c"
          set "number=%%d"
         )
      )
      ren "%%~f#" "!date_!_BOM_!number!%%~x#"
    )
    endlocal
```

Now I am facing the problem that the last line of all my new .txt file have a sign ("") which did not expet and which I would like to delete (maybe delete the whole last line?).

Example

[image]

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: that looks like a "EndOfFile" mark. Try `copy /b ...`

Comment: Great this was solution! @Stephan Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

That's a `EOF` (End Of File). Use `copy` switch `/b` to copy in binary mode (copy byte by byte) instead of text mode:

```
COPY /b %~dp0\PreSet.txt + %~dp0\Header.txt + %~dp0\Item.txt %~dp0\_BOM_.txt
```

Note: if the last line of a file doesn't have a line break at the end, the first line of the next file will be appended to the last line (copy binary means "as is, don't add linebreaks)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with `GNU sed`:

```
sed -i '$ d' yourfile.txt
```

Quick explanation:

- `sed` is a stream editor
- `-i` option stands for `--in-place` and means that we are editing the specified file
- `$` means last line in the file and `d` is the sed command for delete action

Comment: Putting it after "COPY %~dp0\PreSet.txt + %~dp0\Header.txt + %~dp0\Item.txt %~dp0\_BOM_.txt" it has no effect on the final file. The sign stays as shown in the picture...

Comment: This script is supposed to be used on a file like the one in you example, if you want to use it as a stream you need to modify it